# ASP.NET MVC Model binding not parsing

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having some problems getting my ASP.NET MVC application to parse my model, i simply just get "null".

This is my ASP.NET MVC action

```
public AdobeReturnSet<UserModel> Post([FromBody]UserModel model)
```

I have also tried without the [FromBody], that did not help.

This is my model

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public int AdobeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string FristName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(250)]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string OrganizationIdentification { get; set; }

        public string Organization { get; set; }
        public string OrganizationFull { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how i send the request

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset] = "utf-8";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                result = wc.UploadString(url, "POST", data);
            }
```

The url is correct as the correct action is reached and this is the value of data:

```
{"AdobeId":0,"FristName":"Kasper Rune","LastName":"Søgaard","Email":"krus@arcanic.dk","OrganizationIdentification":null,"Organization":null,"OrganizationFull":null}
```

But when the request reaches my action is the model simply null.
It is a ApiController if that changes anything.

Comment: Since you are Posting `JSON`, you don't need `[FromBody]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an encoding problem. Try using the `UploadData` method instead and use UTF-8 encoding:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"{""AdobeId"":0,""FristName"":""Kasper Rune"",""LastName"":""Søgaard"",""Email"":""krus@arcanic.dk"",""OrganizationIdentification"":null,""Organization"":null,""OrganizationFull"":null}");

    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    byte[] result = wc.UploadData(url, "POST", data);
    string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
}
```

Alternatively you could use the new HttpClient:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
    var value = new
    {
        AdobeId = 0,
        FristName = "Kasper Rune",
        LastName = "Søgaard",
        Email = "krus@arcanic.dk",
    };
    var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, value).Result;
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string json = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

Also you might have a typo at `FristName` which should probably be `FirstName`.

Comment: Thank you, your first example worked. I tried your other example as well, but my HttpClient do not contain PostAsJsonAsync, and i am using the 4.0 version? I will wait abit for you to respond before i accept your question!

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` NuGet from the internet. The HttpClient built in .NET doesn't have this method. But you could always use the `client.PostAsync(url, value, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())` method instead.